# Cannot access my web content that i just copied to /op/lampp/htdocs directory?

Tags: nautilus

Now i have copied and pasted my own web file that i previously had created on windows 7. The `gksudo nautilus` command did certainly help me to copy that web file into the `/opt/lampp/htdocs` directory. As now i have my web file in the directory, when i try to access it by browsing it in the browser like `localhost/mywebfile` it pops out the `Access forbidden!` error like

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

Also i cannot access that folder that i just copied to the /opt/lampp/htdocs directory. The error says:-

```
This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “mywebfiles”.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a permission problem.  To avoid this error change permission as shown.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mywebfile
```

Comment: thanks alot @Mitch that definitely helped me out... I was stuck in this problem from yesterday. Thanks alot! Appreciate that!!!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. :)